# Remove top border of GridViewRow in c#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am adding row controls in rowcreated event of gridview and top border line needs to be removed.

```
GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
HeaderCell.Text = strTotalRecords;
HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
HeaderCell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
HeaderGridRow.BackColor = Color.White;
gvGrid.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(totalRowIndex, HeaderGridRow);
```

I am using the below code to remove border and it doesn't work.

```
HeaderCell.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-top", "none");
HeaderCell.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-top-style", "none");

HeaderGridRow.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-top", "none");    
HeaderGridRow.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-top-style", "none");
```

Please suggest me how this can be handled.

Comment: You should do this on client side using _css_ instead of server side.

Answer (score 0):

add a css class to your grid and add style to that css class like below.

```
.gridview
{
    border-top:none !important;
}
```

Comment: These are dynamic controls and I might have to handle here. How about doing like this? `HeaderGridRow.Attributes.Add("class", "cssclassname"); `

Comment: Whether it is static or dynamic, it is not the matter. The above css will set bordor top to none for all the elements with gridview class

Comment: Show me html generated